# Use OpenTopoMap with openLayers 3

Tags: openlayers, layer-resource

In my website, I wish to display a map with few markers of historicals points from a geoJson file.
I start with openlayers 3 api and all is ok, it works.
For the moment I use the OpenStreepMap map that I define like this :

```
`new ol.layer.Tile
    ({
     title: 'OSM',
     type: 'base',
     visible: true,
     source: new ol.source.OSM()
    })`
```

Now I want to replace the OSM map with the openTopoMap ([openTopoMap](http://opentopomap.org)) but I don't know how (can't find parameter)?

Is this possible ?

With what kind of source parameter ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can provide a custom URL to display other OSM layers (or basically any other slippy map layer) via `ol.source.XYZ`, and the source object's `url` property.

```
new ol.layer.Tile({
    title: 'OSM',
    type: 'base',
    visible: true,
    source: new ol.source.XYZ({
        url: 'https://{a|b|c}.tile.opentopomap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
    })
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The correct syntax for OpenLayers 3 is :

```
new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.OSM({
        url: 'https://{a-c}.tile.opentopomap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
    })
});
```

Comment: `ol.source.OSM` is a subclass of `ol.source.XYZ`. So it is better to use the second.